# Telegram bot, quote=False issue

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm having some troubles with the python-telegram-bot. I've been working in a local ubuntu virtual machine with no problems. I've uploaded the .py to a virtual machine on another server (24/7 running) and i run with some issues.
I'm getting this error:

```
telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 555, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 198, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "scriptbot_v7.py", line 77, in opciones
    query.edit_message_text(text=info(), parse_mode='html', quote=False)
TypeError: edit_message_text() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quote'
```

Any ideas why quote is not working anymore? When I delete that it works, but everyone sees what someone else is saying and I preferred that doesn't happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `quote` argument only exists for the `telegram.Message.reply_*` methods. It's just a shortcut for passing the correct `reply_to_message_id`. Because `Bot/CallbackQuery.edit_message_text` doesn't have a  `reply_to_message_id` paramater, there also is no `quote` parameter. This is because while editing a message, you can't change whether it's a reply or not.

> When I delete that it works, but everyone sees what someone else is saying and I preferred that doesn't happend.

Note that is not possible to send messages to group chats that can only be seen by some of the members. Everything posted in a group can be seen by every member of that group.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm not quite sure to know how to fix this. I've tried replacing  query.edit_message_text with update.message.reply_text. That remove the error but everyone is still seeing other people interaction with the bot.

Comment: `query.edit_message_text` and `update.message.reply_text` just do completly different things - the first *edits* an existing message, the second sends a new one. I don't understand the part about "When I delete that it works, but everyone sees what someone else is saying and I preferred that doesn't happend.". Please try to elaborate in your question.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that when i change edit_message_text to update.message.reply_text i don't have the error anymore but quote is not working. When someone interact with the bot whitin a group everyonelse sees that dialog.

Comment: I still don't understand. You pass `reply_text(…, quote=False)` and the message is still a reply? Or what do you mean? Please edit your question above to include a precise description of the problem ;)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a super noob in this. When someone sends a command to the bot (/something) it displays a menu and submenu of options and a final information. That whole process is seeing by everyone in the telegram group. I thought that quote=False is use so that interaction between user and bot is only seen by that particular user and not the rest of the group.

Comment: no, that's absolutely not what it means. messages sent to or edited within a group can be seen by everyone in that group. The sole puprose of the `quote` paramter is providing a shortcut for passing `reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id`.

Comment: Oh Is there a way to do that? I mean, when someone sends a command the user can only see the result and not everyonelse? Thanks in advance

Comment: "messages sent to or edited within a group can be seen by everyone in that group." so no, there is no way to send a message in a group that can only be seen by one person. you'd have to send a message to the user in private chat.